# Python изменение глобальных перменных

Tags: python

Задача такова: есть глобальные перменные, они принимают значение из `config.ini` при запуске. Если изменить файл, изменений этих переменных не происходит. Как заставить переменные менять свои значение, при измени `config.ini`? Все функции считывают данные с глобальных переменных.

Была идея что-то вроде

```
while = True:
 config.read('config.ini')
pass
```

но таким способ я только попадаю в неё и все

Comment: Перечитывать по таймеру конфиг не вариант?

Comment: кстати, кусочек кода с `while = True:` в реальности не заработает ;)

Comment: так надо не постоянно читать конфиг, а постоянно перечитывать его, когда вам надо извлечь из него данные

Comment: @BOPOH я считываю информацию с глобальных переменных, и хотелось бы заставить их перечитывать информацию.

Comment: Можно подписаться на изменение файлов в директории. Подробнее [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599339/python-watchdog-monitoring-file-for-changes) и [тут](http://brunorocha.org/python/watching-a-directory-for-file-changes-with-python.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через определенный таймаут перечитывать значения переменных из файла. Но если вы делаете какой-либо сервис со своими настройками (а если переменные глобальные, то они наверняка важные :)), то на ходу менять какие-либо значения - не очень правильно; хорошо бы предусмотреть механизм старт/стоп/переинициализации параметров.

Comment: таймаут к сожалению не подойдет) не могли бы вы привести пример такого механизма - старт/стоп/переинициализации параметров.

Comment: ну, вы знаете, как обычно разные сервисы в Linux, например, работают? у них есть скрипт (чаще всего) для запуска/рестарта/остановки/получения статуса. Вот, можно подумать в эту сторону. Или опять же, функция с таймаутом, которая будет перечитывать значения и останавливать другие, которые их используют. Но @BOPOH выше правильно сказал, вызывайте открытие конфига с параметрами каждый раз, когда вы работаете с параметрами.

Comment: ну чтож... тогда буду переписывать весь программный код

Comment: @Insider старайтесь сразу следовать принципу декомпозиции и модульности, чтобы из-за каких-то доп. изменений (в данном случае, добавить новую функциональность) не переписывать весь код.

Comment: @Insider я вам предлагаю попробовать добавить функцию, которая будет обновлять значение переменных из файла. Например, `get_params(param)`. И каждый раз, когда вам надо использовать параметр `param`, вызывайте функцию с аргументом в виде параметра, типа `get_param("foo")`.

Comment: к сожалению я пока не разобрал как такие функции в точности работают, поэтому пишу все обходным методом )